# Can anyone tell me what kind of drain this is?

Tags: plumbing, drain

I found this drain in my basement in the middle of a raised rectangle of concrete. Its supposed to be for a shower the previous owner installed. I have never seen this drain type. Looking for answers for what kind of drain it is and why it would have been installed. [image]

Comment: You should either plug that or fill it with water - it's venting sewer gasses when it's dry.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, thanks for [taking our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting; few newbies do.

Comment: @Ecnerwal It looks like the trap is full in that picture - the drain must have been used recently.

Comment: Looks dirty but dry to me. Pictures can lie, of course.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Follow your eye down the edge - it looks like a water line partway between the scum line and the bottom.  You can also see debris floating in the lower left quadrant.

Comment: There is no water line on the removed part @J... so even if it isn't completely dry, the water level is still too low to stop sewer gasses venting through the air gap above the water.

Comment: @MarkBooth I wonder if we're seeing the same picture.  I see a bell trap filled nearly to the level of the central drain hole and a cap with wet sides lifted out of the way.  I'm not sure what the rest of you are seeing.

Answer (score 22):

That is a bone stock "bell-trap" floor drain.

They are illegal for interior use under the IPC (at least) since the trap weir depth is perhaps 1/2 an inch or so; well below the minimum 2" weir depth required, in any case - though in fact the exclusion is for ANY bell-trap, not specific to the depth of the trap, but in this case that is typically about what you'll have.
[1002.3, (Prohibited traps) item number 2 (Bell traps)](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPC2018/chapter-10-traps-interceptors-and-separators)

They can be used for exterior or garage drains (not connected to the sewer) only, as I recall.
I just removed one and "de-trapped" another (cut the inner ring seal so it just acts as a collector) and installed an actual P trap (adjusted to 4" weir depth) on its line. Fun chopping holes in concrete, yes indeed.

It probably was installed for a shower. They look like a perfectly reasonable, easy to clean option and the large box store will happily sell them without telling you that they are illegal for interior applications.

Comment: As to why it was installed, it's likely because of it's minimal depth, meaning that there was less need to excavate, and possibly the drain line could have been placed higher.

Comment: In fact, a proper P-Trap floor drain (with the trap and a cleanout built in) gets the drain line higher than these do unless you double-trap them (also illegal under IPC and most [all?] other codes)

Comment: The reason that they're illegal is that the shallow weir dries up quickly (in as little as a few days) and the trap fails when that happens.  A proper p-trap takes 4-6 months to dry out, by contrast.  If OP has such a trap and it's connected to the sewer and they don't want to remove it right away, it would be important to at least throw a bit of water into it every few days to keep the trap sealed.

Answer (score 6):

Looks to me like some sort of ultra-low-profile trap. When the top section is in place, the channel will fill up and overflow into the central drain. Water will remain in the channel, to stop nasty niffs.